# Jaws doesn't read table cell content

Tags: html, confluence, jaws-screen-reader

I am trying to make table readable by jaws.
What are the necessary aria tag needed to make it readable.

```html
<table class="wrapped confluenceTable">
   <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col>
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="confluenceTh">Index</th>
         <th class="confluenceTh">Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="confluenceTd">12</td>
         <td class="confluenceTd">suresh sakhare</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don’t see anything relating to a “view” and an “edit” mode in that code snippet you have shown.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldnt need any aria tags to get that table to read. Semantically the code is wrong.  should be wrapped around the 's and  should wrap around only the 's.